# How to Disable the output steam printed as output while opening a Webpage via JAVA swing application

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I am trying to open a website link via java swing GUI application, I am able to do so but in the process I am getting some unwanted output in the console

below is the piece of code to open a Webpage I used,

```
JLabel MyLabel = new JLabel("open Google.com");
MyLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.google.com/"));
                } 
                catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) 
                {
                    UserLogin.SetMSGDialog("Unable to open www.google.com");
                }
            }       
        }
});
```

**Console Output:**

```
(process:18534): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OutputStream emptyOutputStream = new OutputStream() {
     @Override
     public void write(int arg0) throws IOException {
     }
}
PrintStream emptyPrintStream = new PrintStream(emptyOutputStream);
System.setOut(emptyPrintStream);
```

And the same action for System.setErr

Comment: This will disable every output from the application.

Comment: Yes, may be helpful utility, that can replace system.out and then can return back previous value... disable for some time if you want

Comment: Stranger in the Q I tried your solution but still I am getting the console output

Comment: did you replace System.err too?